# number that should be returned is the first or last in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

i have got test scenarios for certain cases in my jasmine..
but i am not able to get the test cases for this three scenarios...
can you tell me how to do it...

- the number that should be returned is the first or last in the array
  undefined values in the array (or NaN, Infinity, …)\ numbers with
  identical absolute values (e.g. -0.01 and 0.01)

providing my fiddle too

http://jsfiddle.net/YYg8U/15/

```
var myNumbersToSort = [-1, 2, -3, 4, 0.3,1,-0.001];


function getClosestToZero(set) {
  if(0 === set.length) return null;
  var closest = Math.abs(set[0]), result = 0;
  for(var i in set) {
     var next = Math.abs(set[i]);
     if(closest > next) {
       result = i;
       closest = next;
     }
  }
  return closest;  
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = (getClosestToZero(myNumbersToSort));
```

jasmine

```
describe( 'getClosestToZero', function () {
    it( 'finds a positive unique number near zero', function () {
        expect( getClosestToZero( [-1, 0.5, 0.01, 3, -0.2] ) ).toBe( 0.01 );
    } );

    it( 'finds a negative unique number near zero', function () {
        expect( getClosestToZero( [-1, 0.5, -0.01, 3, -0.2] ) ).toBe( -0.01 );
    } );

    // your method actually doesn't pass this test
    // think about what your method *should* do here and if needed, fix it
    it( 'finds one of multiple identical numbers near zero', function () {
        expect( getClosestToZero( [-1, 0.5, 0.01, 0.01, 3, -0.2] ) ).toBe( 0.01 );
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Looking at the code, I'd imagine that your test doesn't pass the second test but should pass the third. This is because you compare and return the absolute value of the value. So the second test will return 0.01 as opposed to -0.01

Comment: @cbayram: thanks for your reply..can you edit my fiddle and how to pass second test http://jsfiddle.net/YYg8U/15/

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to maintain your current code and not optimize it.

```
function getClosestToZero(set) {
  if(0 === set.length) return null;
  // you are assigning the actual value to the closest variable
  var closest = set[0], result = 0;
  for(var i in set) {
    // you are assigning the actual value to the next variable
    var next = set[i];
    // you are comparing the absolute values
    if(Math.abs(closest) > Math.abs(next)) {
      result = i;
      // but you are assigning the actual value
      closest = next;
    }
  }
  // thus your return value is the actual number and not its absolute
  return closest;  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N4HLT/

You can use the isNaN() function to test whether an entry is not a number or perhaps typeof next == "number" might be more appropriate should you not desire boolean and string numerical values for instance (e.g. "2", false will ARE numbers according to the isNaN test)

**UPDATED**

```
function getClosestToZeroWithNaN(set) {
  var closest;
  if(set instanceof Array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        var val = set[i];
        if(!isNaN(val)) {
            val = Number(val);
            var absVal = Math.abs(val);
            if(typeof closest == 'undefined' || Math.abs(closest) > absVal) {
                closest = val; 
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return closest;
}
function getClosestToZeroOnlyNumbers(set) {
  var closest;
  if(set instanceof Array) {
    for(var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        var val = set[i];
        if(typeof val == "number") {
            var absVal = Math.abs(val);
            if(typeof closest == 'undefined' || Math.abs(closest) > absVal) {
                closest = val; 
            }
        }
    }
  }
  return closest;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hB2T8/ look at how NaN version treats null, false and "2.12"

Comment: thanks for your reply...but what abt this scenarios 
    the number that should be returned is the first or last in the array undefined values in the array (or NaN, Infinity, …)\ numbers with identical absolute values (e.g. -0.01 and 0.01)

Comment: @user3102494 I'm confused and don't understand what that means. Do you mean that the function should return both -0.01 AND 0.01 if they are the closest to zero? Furthermore, what is meant by "the array undefined values in the array (or NaN, Infinity, …)\"?

Comment: Do you mean that the function should return both -0.01 AND 0.01 if they are the closest to zero?...not sure what to return for this condition...what you suggest

Comment: @user3102494, lol, I don't understand your condition. Furthermore, I'm indifferent to what it returns. If the idea is to get the number closest to zero as the name implies check out the updated answer section.

Comment: @cybayram: thanks for your reply...instead of writing three different functions is it possible to get it combined in one function...i mean everything in one scenario...http://jsfiddle.net/hB2T8/

Comment: @user3102494, all 3 do different things. If you are at a fork in the road, can you take a left and a right? No, you have to make a decision based on your requirements. I suggest you understand what the functions do, how they differ and what your exact requirements are wherever you are getting them.

Comment: yeah everything i should put it in one function...can you put in the fiddle